# Google Spread Sheet Search any part of the cell and display

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code to search and display the exact field in any column.

I would like to get the code of partial search, such that the input value if we entre is partial, should display all the possible fields.

Eg. Search "Evaluation" in the search field should display all the possible results.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpZ93.jpg)

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}


/* PROCESS FORM */
function processForm(formObject){  
  var result = "";
  if(formObject.searchtext){//Execute if form passes search text
      result = search(formObject.searchtext);
  }
  return result;
}

//SEARCH FOR MATCHED CONTENTS 
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = '1iG30kufq5MQpd0xmoPhPir5iA3hlz8s7vI_0EWQfg7Q'; //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRage        = 'Data!A2:Y';                                    //** CHANGE !!!
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRage).values;
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(searchtext)) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        <script>
          //PREVENT FORMS FROM SUBMITTING / PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
          function preventFormSubmit() {
            var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
            for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
              forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              });
            }
          }
          window.addEventListener("load", preventFormSubmit, true); 
             
          
          //HANDLE FORM SUBMISSION
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processForm(formObject);
            document.getElementById("search-form").reset();
          }
        
          //CREATE THE DATA TABLE
          function createTable(dataArray) {
            if(dataArray && dataArray !== undefined && dataArray.length != 0){
              var result = "<table class='table table-sm table-striped' id='dtable' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+
                           "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+
                             "<tr>"+                               //Change table headings to match witht he Google Sheet
                              "<th scope='col'>MS No</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Title</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Status</th>"+
                              "<th scope='col'>Date</th>"+
                            "</tr>"+
                          "</thead>";
              for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
                  result += "<tr>";
                  for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
                      result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
                  }
                  result += "</tr>";
              }
              result += "</table>";
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              div.innerHTML = result;
            }else{
              var div = document.getElementById('search-results');
              //div.empty()
              div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
            }
          }
        </script>
        <!--##JAVASCRIPT FUNCTIONS ~ END ---------------------------------------------------- -->
        
    </head>
    <body>
          <div class="container">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  <form id="search-form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                      <label for="searchtext">Search MS No</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" placeholder="Enter MS No">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Search</button>
                  </form>
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ~ END ------------------------------------------- -->
              
              </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ------------------------------------------------ -->
                <div id="search-results" class="table-responsive">
                  <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
                </div>
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  <form id="search-form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                      <label for="searchtext">Search Title</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" placeholder="Enter Title">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Search</button>
                  </form>
                  <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ~ END ------------------------------------------- -->
              
              </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
            
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ------------------------------------------------ -->
                <div id="search-results" class="table-responsive">
                  <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
                </div>
                <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------------------ -->
                  
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What code do you want to get? Is it Index.html's code? If you have already made the HTML code even if it is still incomplete, could you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

This will highlight partial substring matches in red:

```
function searchhilight() {
  let hilite = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor('red').build();
  let normal = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(false).setForegroundColor('black').build();
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const rg = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  rg.setFontColor('black').setFontWeight('normal');//set all data to black text with no bold
  const dvs = rg.getDisplayValues();
  const resp = ui.prompt('Search Text', 'Enter Search String', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (resp.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    const st = resp.getResponseText();
    dvs.forEach((r, i) => {
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        let idx = '';
        fidx = '';//from index
        iA = [];//index array of matches
        do {
          idx = c.indexOf(st, fidx);
          if (~idx) {
            fidx = idx + st.length;
            iA.push({ idxs: idx, idxe: idx + st.length })
          }
        } while (~idx);
        let rtv = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(c);
        iA.forEach(obj => rtv.setTextStyle(obj.idxs, obj.idxe, hilite));
        sh.getRange(i + sr, j + 1).setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
        sh.getRange(i + sr, j + 1).setRichTextValue(rtv.build());
      });
    });
  }
}
```

This function will also reformat every cell in the data range to plain text.

[RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#setTextStyle(Integer,Integer,TextStyle))

[RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)

Comment: I have updated html code. Kindly modify in my existing code. Am not a developer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function search(searchtext){
  var spreadsheetId   = '1do6G8pScBAz0Z7GOCjbBcXPKJkhbOwlSx5BZyt6S7H8'; //** CHANGE !!!
  var dataRage        = 'Data!A2:Y';                                    //** CHANGE !!!
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, dataRage).values;
  var ar = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchtext.toString().toLowerCase())) {
      ar.push(f);
    }
  });
  return ar;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).